# Kitura TypeSafeHTTPBasic auth looking for credentials in post body?

Tags: swift, rest, kitura

I have a TypeSafe Codeable route in Kitura defined like this:

```
app.router.post("/games") { (auth: BasicAuth, respondWith: @escaping (Game?, RequestError?) -> ()) in 
    ...
}
```

But when I make a get request, I receive `Could not decode received JSON: The required key 'id' not found.`. This seems like the router is attempting to parse the `auth` object from the POST body rather than from the basic auth header. If I change the route to GET it works just fine, but I don't understand the Type Safe Codeable routing very well and I'm confused about what changed with the POST route. How do I get my `BasicAuth` to work the same with POST as with GET?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When using Kitura's Codable Routing, a POST handler expects to receive a Codable input from the message body.  You can optionally specify one or more TypeSafeMiddleware requirements.

If you want to perform a POST, you would want to match [the post() function on Router](https://github.com/IBM-Swift/Kitura/blob/2.4.1/Sources/Kitura/CodableRouter%2BTypeSafeMiddleware.swift#L1169) that takes a Codable and a TypeSafeMiddleware as inputs:

```
app.router.post("/games") { (auth: BasicAuth, input: MyInputType, respondWith: @escaping (Game?, RequestError?) -> ()) in 
    ...
}
```

What's happening in your case is that you are actually matching [this post() function without TypeSafeMiddleware](https://github.com/IBM-Swift/Kitura/blob/2.4.1/Sources/Kitura/CodableRouter.swift#L291), where your auth type (which conforms to Codable) is being interpreted as your input type.

If you do not expect to POST a payload to the server for this request, perhaps what you want instead is a GET which instead matches [the get() function on Router](https://github.com/IBM-Swift/Kitura/blob/2.4.1/Sources/Kitura/CodableRouter%2BTypeSafeMiddleware.swift#L52) that only takes a TypeSafeMiddleware as input:

```
app.router.get("/games") { (auth: BasicAuth, respondWith: @escaping (Game?, RequestError?) -> ()) in 
    ...
}
```

Note that the TypeSafeMiddleware are the first parameter(s) to the route handlers, followed by any other input types (in the case of PUT or POST).